# Comparing answers and solutions in R (i.e., comparing two table)

Tags: r

I have two tables, 1. answers table and 2. solution table.

The answer table is a list of Name+Answer.

```
name=c("Jenns","Amy","Jake","Alison","Tommy","Jason","Alex","Vivian")
guess_answer=c("sdgf23894011","lp98ung67543","pwerugji22im","21loop98un89","9580ik8584sf","awe25f6ty788","k0o2jgpo146i","rgyhuj87630l")
answer=data.frame(cbind(name,guess_answer))
> answer
    name guess_answer
1  Jenns sdgf23894011
2    Amy lp98ung67543
3   Jake pwerugji22im
4 Alison 21loop98un89
5  Tommy 9580ik8584sf
6  Jason awe25f6ty788
7   Alex k0o2jgpo146i
8 Vivian rgyhuj87630l
```

The solution table is lists of country with a corresponding (digit+alphabet).

```
corresponding_number=c("2341rg4524gr","9580ik7584sf","pp0or9rjg7n2","g0o2jgpo146i","lp98ung67543","pwerugji22im","lokibh678901")
country=c("US","UK","CN","AU","JP","KR", "NP")
counry_name=c("United State","United Kingdom","China","Australia","Japan","Korea","North Pole")
solution = cbind(country, corresponding_number,counry_name)
solution = data.frame(solution)
> solution
  country corresponding_number    counry_name
1      US         2341rg4524gr   United State
2      UK         9580ik7584sf United Kingdom
3      CN         pp0or9rjg7n2          China
4      AU         g0o2jgpo146i      Australia
5      JP         lp98ung67543          Japan
6      KR         pwerugji22im          Korea
7      NP         lokibh678901     North Pole
```

I would like to compare the answer table to the solution table, in which if the guess_number is the exact same or 1 digit/alphabet different, it is consider as correct. Then I want to create a table with the country, corresponding_number, and the counry_name.
For example:

```
> newtable
     name  corresponding_number country_name    
[1,] "xxx" "sdgf23894011"       "xxx"           
[2,] "JP"  "lp98ung67543"       "Japan"         
[3,] "KR"  "pwerugji22im"       "Korea"         
[4,] "xxx" "21loop98un89"       "xxx"           
[5,] "UK"  "9580ik8584sf"       "United Kingdom"
[6,] "xxx" "awe25f6ty788"       "xxx"           
[7,] "AU"  "k0o2jgpo146i"       "Australia"     
[8,] "xxx" "rgyhuj87630l"       "xxx"
```

1. The name needs to be: either replaced by "xxx" if answer is wrong, or the "country abbreviations" if answer is wrong.
2. whether the answer is correct or wrong is based on the guess_answer; the guess_answer is correct if it is a)exactly the same as one of the corresponding_number, or b)1 digit/alphabet different.
3. the guess_answer will not change but the colname will become "corresponding_number"
4. Include a third columns showing the full country name, if the guess_answer is wrong, the responding full country name will be "xxx" as well .

edit: first condition.

Comment: Please don't use `data.frame(cbind` as it can mess up the types, instead just do `data.frame(`

Comment: is `data.frame()` in default cbind?

Comment: Yes, it is. `cbind` have method `cbind.data.frame`.  But if you do it without specifying it, it would call the `matrix` method, to bind it and result in `matrix` which can hold only a single class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one option is `stringdist_left_join`,  after the join and `mutate` to `replace` the `NA` elements with 'xxx'

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
stringdist_left_join(answer, solution, 
      by = c("guess_answer" = "corresponding_number"))%>% 
   mutate(corresponding_number = case_when(is.na(corresponding_number)
         ~ guess_answer, TRUE ~ corresponding_number),
          name = case_when(is.na(country) ~ 'xxx', TRUE ~ country), 
          counry_name = replace(counry_name, is.na(counry_name), 'xxx')) %>% 
   select(name, corresponding_number = guess_answer, counry_name)
#  name corresponding_number    counry_name
#1  xxx         sdgf23894011            xxx
#2   JP         lp98ung67543          Japan
#3   KR         pwerugji22im          Korea
#4  xxx         21loop98un89            xxx
#5   UK         9580ik8584sf United Kingdom
#6  xxx         awe25f6ty788            xxx
#7   AU         k0o2jgpo146i      Australia
#8  xxx         rgyhuj87630l            xxx
```

#### data

```
answer <- data.frame(name,guess_answer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
solution <- data.frame(country, corresponding_number, 
           counry_name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I got an error when opening the library,
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fuzzyjoin’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required

Comment: @MathAvengers  I think you need a higher version of `rlang`.  I have `packageVersion('rlang')
[1] ‘0.4.0’`  Please update your package

Comment: may you please explain a little bit on the code, where you use mutate() and is.na(), thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `adist`.

```
#Calculate distance between guess_answer and corresponding_number
mat <- adist(answer$guess_answer, solution$corresponding_number)
#assign default value to result column
answer$country_name <- 'xxx'
#select values with distance of less than or equal to 1
mat1 <- which(mat <= 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
#Order them by row
ord <- order(mat1[, 1])
#Assign values to the column
answer$country_name[mat1[ord, 1]] <- solution$counry_name[mat1[ord, 2]]

answer
#    name guess_answer   country_name
#1  Jenns sdgf23894011            xxx
#2    Amy lp98ung67543          Japan
#3   Jake pwerugji22im          Korea
#4 Alison 21loop98un89            xxx
#5  Tommy 9580ik8584sf United Kingdom
#6  Jason awe25f6ty788            xxx
#7   Alex k0o2jgpo146i      Australia
#8 Vivian rgyhuj87630l            xxx
```

**data**

```
answer <- data.frame(name,guess_answer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
solution <- data.frame(country, corresponding_number,counry_name, 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```